# Visual Studio 2022, Form refactoring and text boxes issue

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, winforms, refactoring

I'm a very newb and know nothing about any IDEs, I've encountered a problem where if I change "Form1" to any other name with proper refactoring it won't add any textBox in the solution explorer, I will see the textbox in the [Design] form but not in the code.

Can someone explain me how to rename things without Visual Studio losing total trace of objects ?

Eventually how can I insert objects manually via code, I know there is a solution but I don't know where find this code to generate an object.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us5xI.png)

I appreciate any help, not that I've started C# a couple weeks ago.

Comment: Calling it just "Form" may cause a conflict with the base class "Form" - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form?view=windowsdesktop-6.0 - you should consider choosing a different name

Comment: You should active the error list `CTRL + W, E` or in the menu `View -> Error List` this should open a list of errors at the bottom, I believe you may have a few because of that conflict

Comment: Close all open Files before renaming the form in the Solution Explorer.

Comment: Yes, @RandRandom is right. You  cannot call a form `Form`. The original code was `public partial class Form1 : Form`. Now, if you rename `Form1` to `Form` you are trying to derive a class named like its base class. And this causes problems. (They will be in different namespaces, so. But where the name `Form` is not prefixed with the namespace, you will have a conflict when you you have a `using System.Windows.Forms;`.)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If an answer solves your problem you could click '✔' to mark it as an acceptable answer. If it helps you give it an upvote. If the answer is offtopic or doesn’t help at all, downvote or add a comment. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Answer (score 1):

How you change the name of the form is important.

If you simply open the code file and change it's name in the `.cs` file, that's going to fail pretty quickly. A `.designer.cs` file sits behind the `.cs` file and contains all the controls, and it thinks the name of the form is `Form1`.

The best way to rename a form is to either:

1. Use the Visual Studio shortcut to open the Rename dialog. (For me, the shortcut is `CTRL+R+R`. For you, it may be `F2`.) Use the dialog to type in a new name and press `enter`. This will change the form's name everywhere it appears in the solution.
2. Right-click on the form in **Solution Explorer**. Select **Rename** from the menu that appears. Type in the new name for the file and press `enter`. When prompted to rename the type to match the file name, select `Yes`. This will also change the form's name everywhere it appears.

Answer (score 0):

For Form name change:
Select Form Design
Press F4 (Properties of Form)
Form's Properties will open
Goto Form Name Option
Change the Name and press enter
Your form name gets changed successfully.

Open Form.Designer.cs for codeing of the designing part.

Comment: Changing the `Name` propery in the properties window will rename the class but leave the .cs, .designer.cs and .resx file names, which will be really confusing!